# How to underline a Title in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I want to underline the Text of a button in xamarin iOS, i have a style called

```
    public static UIButton StyleLinkButtonBlack(this UIButton button)
    {
        button.Font = Styles.SetOpenSansSemiboldFont(Dimensions.medium);
        button.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);     
        button.TitleLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

        return button;
    }
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to add a NSMutableAttributedString, like that

```
var attrString = new NSMutableAttributedString(button.TitleLabel.Text);
attrString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle,NSNumber.FromInt32((int)NSUnderlineStyle.Single),new NSRange(0, attrString.Length));
button.TitleLabel.AttributedText = attrString;
```